# optimizing controls Top-down by parent

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

According to this post
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446535.aspx
you can do some optimization on your code.
I am wondering if anyone getting some success, as I've tried out and can't get performance.

Regards,
Pentium10

Comment: Doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  The real cost of a form with a lot of controls is in displaying it, not creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might gain you something, but it's going to be negligible when your form only has a few controls on it.

Keep in mind as well that the article is from 2002 and was talking about .NET Compact Framework 1.0. Things might have changed in later .NET CF versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea since the performance improvement would be minor and once you make those "optimizations" you can't use the the Forms Designer to make any additional changes to the form.

Essentially you will be hand coding all of your forms which defeats the biggest reason for using CF.  If performance is that important you shouldn't be using CF in the first place.